# Dovecot mailbox_list_index not recognised

Tags: dovecot

I have dovecot installation and I want to enable indexing (e.g. faster retrieval of IMAP STAT command)

If I do:

```
# doveconf | grep mailbox_list_index
mailbox_list_index = no
```

I see dovecot have this option.

However if I add into conf file:

```
mailbox_list_index = yes
```

I get:

```
Starting Dovecot Imap: doveconf: Fatal: Error in configuration file /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf line 7: Unknown setting: mailbox_list_index
```

I do not seems to find any information about this.

Dovecot version is 2.0.9.

Config file is just this:

```
base_dir = /var/run/dovecot/
disable_plaintext_auth = no
ssl = no

first_valid_uid = 1000

mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir

# Outlook Express and Windows Mail works only with LOGIN mechanism, not the standard PLAIN:
auth_mechanisms = plain login

#mailbox_list_index = no

service auth {
    user = root
    unix_listener /var/spool/postfix.host/private/auth {
        mode = 0666
        user = postfix
        group = postfix
    }
}

userdb {
    args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/BASE/%d/%n mail=maildir:/BASE/%d/%n
    driver = static
}

passdb {
    args = username_format=%n /BASE.PASS/%d
    driver = passwd-file
}

protocols = pop3 imap
#protocols = imap

service pop3 {
}

service imap {
}

service imap-login {
    inet_listener imap {
        address = *
        port = 143
    }
}
```

On this server I will have some maildirs with 100,000+ messages, so any other improvements will be welcome.

Comment: Please provide more context of your configuration, at least where you put the option (given this is line seven, posting the whole first bunch of lines would likely be a good selection). Also, provide which release of Dovecot you're using.

Comment: question updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dovecot 2.0.9 is *very* outdated (released January 2011!), and the list index was not introduced before Dovecot 2.1.0. Upgrade to a more recent release to use the list index directive. Updating will bring many other fixes and performance improvements.

Anyway, the most relevant improvement in performance will be converting the mailboxes from the MailDir format to the superior [mdbox](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailboxFormat/dbox?highlight=%28mdbox%29), one of Dovecot's most important features especially for large mail systems. Furthermore, Dovecot has a [whole documentation section on performance tuning](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/PerformanceTuning), deciding on the relevant ones requires collecting information on usage patterns and some hardware benchmarking.